# Set query parameters of RFC_READ_TABLE using win32com module?

Tags: python, win32com, saprfc

I'm trying to port to Python a SAP table download script, that already works on Excel VBA, but I want a command line version and I would prefer to avoid VBScript for a number of reasons that go beyond the goal of this post.

I'm stuck at the moment in which I need to fill the values in a table

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
Functions = Dispatch("SAP.Functions")

Functions.Connection.Client = "400"
Functions.Connection.ApplicationServer = "myserver"
Functions.Connection.Language = "EN"
Functions.Connection.User = "myuser"
Functions.Connection.Password = "mypwd"
Functions.Connection.SystemNumber = "00"
Functions.Connection.UseSAPLogonIni = False
if (Functions.Connection.Logon (0,True) == True):
    print("Logon OK")
    RFC = Functions.Add("RFC_READ_TABLE")
    RFC.exports("QUERY_TABLE").Value = "USR02"
    RFC.exports("DELIMITER").Value = "~"
    #RFC.exports("ROWSKIPS").Value = 2000
    #RFC.exports("ROWCOUNT").Value = 10

    tblOptions = RFC.Tables("OPTIONS")
    #RETURNED DATA
    tblData = RFC.Tables("DATA")
    tblFields = RFC.Tables("FIELDS")

    tblFields.AppendRow ()

    print(tblFields.RowCount)
    print(tblFields(1,"FIELDNAME"))
    # the 2 lines above print 1 and an empty string, so the row in the table exists
```

Until here it is basically copied from VBA adapting the syntax.
In VBA at this point I'm able to do

```
tblFields(1,"FIELDNAME") = "BNAME"
```

if I do the same I get an error because the left part is a function and written that way it returns a string. In VBA it is *probably* a bi-dimensional array.

I unsuccessfully tried various approaches like

```
tblFields.setValue([{"FIELDNAME":"BNAME"}])
tblFields(1,"FIELDNAME").Value = "BNAME"
tblFields(1,"FIELDNAME").setValue("BNAME")
tblFields.FieldName = "BNAME" ##kinda desperate
```

The script works, without setting the FIELDS table, for outputs that produce rows shorter than 500 chars. This is a SAP limit in the function.

I know that this is not the best way, but I can't use the SAPNWRFC library and I can't use librfc32.dll.
I must be able to solve this way, or revert to the VB version.

Thanks to anyone who will provide a hint

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error, i found a solution.
Instead of adding row by row to the "OPTIONS" or "FIELDS" tables, you can just submit a prefilled table.
This should work:

```
tblFields.Data = (('VBELN', '000000', '000000', '', ''),
                  ('POSNR', '000000', '000000', '', ''))
```

same here:

```
tblOptions.Data = (("VBELN EQ '2557788'",),)
```